# How to send a special keyboard sequence using Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, keyboard, remote-access

I use official [Microsoft client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android) and I need to "press" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: Your PC (node_1) and Remote PC (node_2).

Open the onscreen keyboard Start -> All Programs -> Accesories -> Ease of Access -> On-Screen Keyboard on node_2.

When you want to send ctrl+alt+del, press Ctrl+Alt in node_1 and click del in node_2. (Worked for me in node_1=XP and node_2=Win7)